# Visual Studio randomly scrambles my markup code (designer)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I don't know if anyone has seen this behavior or found a work-around.  Googling has not turned up anything yet.
From time to time, when I execute my code, Visual Studio 2017 will pick a spot in my code, delete what was there, and insert a bunch of "garbage".  It looks like:

```
#ExternalSource ("<physical file location>.aspx", 7)
        __o = hidInvoicesToPay.ClientID

#End ExternalSource
```

It can be one line or many many lines with different files.  I have found no way to replicate this.  It just seems to happen at random times.  It *may* have something to do with changing the markup while the debugger is running.  At least it seems to happen most that way.  It could be coincidence though.

Has anyone seen this or found a fix?

Thanks.

P.S. I am running Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise with a ASP Web Forms app, including Entity Framework 6, Web API, and the standard add-ons & NuGet packages for this type of project.

Comment: I have noticed this happening too. Not just with those #ExternalSource lines either. It will completely delete something, or even replace variables with other ones! Only way I could tell what it scrambled was to compare with what was in Git. Seriously annoying.

Comment: It seems to only happen when I am changing code while running.

Comment: Come to think of it, I think that's what happened to me as well. I was debugging and I changed the aspx markup. Then everything went scrambled. Seems like a VS bug.

Comment: Happens to me even when not debugging.

Comment: It stopped after a while, but as of VS 17.7.4 (updated this week) it is happening again!

Comment: Just now it happened when I updated code, saved the file, then clicked the Play button (F5).  I was watching closely this time and it didn't appear until after the debug started.

Comment: Same thing, Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) , Version 17.8.6. happening on VB.NET ASP.NET project. Impossible to work because it happens on total random places. Since it is not free software how can it be MS did not resolve this issue for so long?